# How to I find the full path of an application or file in linux?

Tags: matlab, path, directory

I have to manually add paths to multiple files in a matlab script, i.e. my matlab directory or startup.m, but i am unsure as to how to find the full file path for either of these on a unix system

I have tried find, which, whereis, but none seem to provide the full file path

ie

whereis matlab

find matlab

Answer (score 1):

[`matlabroot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabroot.html) returns the directory where MATLAB is installed:

```
p = matlabroot;
```

The MATLAB executable is typically in `fullfile(matlabroot,'bin','matlab')`.

To find the location of an M-file that is on the MATLAB path, use [`which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html):

```
p = which('startup')
```